# How to append a whole obj into a other obj without wrapping into array

Tags: javascript, json, object

i try to add this little obj function here:

```
      function addLocationToGeoJson(lng, lat) {
        let geoObj = {};

        // THIS OBJ BELOW NEED TO BE IN "geoJson"
        const geoItem = {
          type: "Feature",
          geometry: {
            type: "Point",
            coordinates: [lng, lat]
          }
        }
        geoJson = Object.assign(geoObj, geoItem);
        return geoJson;
      }
```

into this obj:

```
      let geoJson = {};
```

i am doing this in a forEach:

```
      lngLatLocation.forEach((item) => {
        createListItem(item);
        addLocationToGeoJson(item.coordinates[0], item.coordinates[1]);
      });
```

i need to do this without wrapping it into a array and using push

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to combine json. You can use ES6

```
const geoItem = {
          type: "Feature",
          geometry: {
            type: "Point",
            coordinates: [lng, lat]
          }
        }

let geoJson={...geoItem}
```

Here is a link to the documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Operadores/Spread_operator